# WinRT WebView events are not firing?

Tags: c#, webview, event-handling, windows-runtime

I have a C# WinRT app that uses the WebView control.  None of the events I have created event handlers for are firing:

```
Uri theUri = new Uri("http://bing.com/");

webViewVideoPlayer.NavigationStarting += webViewVideoPlayer_NavigationStarting;
webViewVideoPlayer.NavigationCompleted += webViewVideoPlayer_NavigationCompleted;
webViewVideoPlayer.ContentLoading += webViewVideoPlayer_ContentLoading;
webViewVideoPlayer.NavigationFailed += webViewVideoPlayer_NavigationFailed;

webBrowserVideoPlayer.Navigate(theUri);
```

I have set breakpoints on the first line in each of the event handler bodies.  The web page renders fine, but none of the breakpoints are hit.  What can I do to fix this?

The app is currently configured for Debug build, x86 platform.

[TO THE MODERATORS: This is not my best post obviously.  I was tired and made a silly mistake.  If you feel it is best to delete it, please do.]

Comment: Ha! I looked at it and just assumed your webViewVideoPlayer was part of the webBrowserVideoPlayer template and shrugged. Never assumed those were unrelated! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two different control names in your code. The events are attached to `webViewVideoPlayer`, yet later the `Navigate` is called on a different `WebView` called `webBrowserVideoPlayer.`

I did a test with a WebView and the events were called as expected.

Comment: Ouch, just pulled an all-nighter.  Thanks.